# Segmentation Fault (11) on create new object in android

Tags: android, delphi, segmentation-fault, delphi-xe7

I get a segfault when I call `FPlatformNetworkState := TPlatformNetworkState.Create;` in the below code.

What I know about segfault 11 is that it happens when I try to access memory that I'm not allowed to (similar to an AccessViolation in Windows). But since I am creating a new instance, shouldn't it get new memory allocated?

How should I create it instead so that it won't access memory that it shouldn't?

Full unit:

```
unit UNetworkState;

{From http://delphi.radsoft.com.au/2013/11/checking-for-an-internet-connection-on-mobile-devices-with-delphi-xe5/ (16-2-2015)}

interface

type
  TCustomNetworkState = class(TObject)
    function CurrentSSID: string; virtual; abstract;
    function IsConnected: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
    function IsWifiConnected: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
    function IsMobileConnected: Boolean; virtual; abstract;
  end;

  TNetworkState = class(TCustomNetworkState)
  private
    FPlatformNetworkState: TCustomNetworkState;
  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function CurrentSSID: string;
    function IsConnected: Boolean; override;
    function IsWifiConnected: Boolean; override;
    function IsMobileConnected: Boolean; override;
  end;

implementation

uses
{$IFDEF IOS}
  //NetworkState.iOS;
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  UNetworkStateAndroid;
{$ENDIF}

{ TNetworkState }

constructor TNetworkState.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FPlatformNetworkState := TPlatformNetworkState.Create;
end;

destructor TNetworkState.Destroy;
begin
  FPlatformNetworkState.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TNetworkState.CurrentSSID: string;
begin
  Result := FPlatformNetworkState.CurrentSSID;
end;

function TNetworkState.IsConnected: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FPlatformNetworkState.IsConnected;
end;

function TNetworkState.IsMobileConnected: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FPlatformNetworkState.IsMobileConnected;
end;

function TNetworkState.IsWifiConnected: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FPlatformNetworkState.IsWifiConnected;
end;

end.
```

Form where the create is called:

```
unit UMainForm;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Types,
  System.UITypes,
  System.Classes,
  System.Variants,
  FMX.Types,
  FMX.Graphics,
  FMX.Controls,
  FMX.Forms,
  FMX.Dialogs,
  FMX.TabControl,
  FMX.StdCtrls,
  FMX.Gestures;

type
  TappMainForm = class(TForm)
    HeaderToolBar: TToolBar;
    ToolBarLabel: TLabel;
    TabControl1: TTabControl;
    TabItem1: TTabItem;
    TabItem2: TTabItem;
    TabItem3: TTabItem;
    TabItem4: TTabItem;
    GestureManager1: TGestureManager;
    NotificationsPanel: TPanel;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormGesture(Sender: TObject; const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo;
      var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure EmbedForm(ArgParent : TControl; ArgForm : TCustomForm);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  appMainForm: TappMainForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
uses
  UNetworkState;

procedure TappMainForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  NS : TNetworkState;
begin
  { This defines the default active tab at runtime }
  TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabItem1;

  NS.Create;
  try
    if not NS.IsConnected then begin
      ShowMessage('No network connection detected.'#13#10'Please connect to the internet in your device''s settings.');
    end else if NS.IsWifiConnected then begin
      ShowMessage('WiFi connection detected.');
    end else if NS.IsMobileConnected then begin
      ShowMessage('Mobile connection detected.');
    end;
  finally
    NS.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TappMainForm.FormGesture(Sender: TObject;
  const EventInfo: TGestureEventInfo; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
  case EventInfo.GestureID of
    sgiLeft:
    begin
      if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> TabControl1.Tabs[TabControl1.TabCount-1] then
        TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabControl1.Tabs[TabControl1.TabIndex+1];
      Handled := True;
    end;

    sgiRight:
    begin
      if TabControl1.ActiveTab <> TabControl1.Tabs[0] then
        TabControl1.ActiveTab := TabControl1.Tabs[TabControl1.TabIndex-1];
      Handled := True;
    end;
  end;
{$ENDIF}
end;
end.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Access Violation here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617288/why-access-violation-here)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Form code, calling `NS.Create` is wrong.  It needs to be `NS := TNetworkState.Create` instead.